# Problem on loading data in datatable using json C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

This my `jQuery` code:

[image: click to view jquery image]

Here's how my controller is like.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Details(string name)
{
    var model = db.PurchaseRepo.Get(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || x.Name.Contains(name));
    var final = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<IList<PurchaseViewModel>>(model);
    return Json(final,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: click enter image for jquery code

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: i think you didn't provide the "name" parameter

Comment: In your browser press F12--> Network tab in order to verify if there's any traffic at all.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya data is not being load in the datatables

Comment: @HemantAcharya Define your `DataTable` as: `"url": "@Url.Action("details", "purchase")","method": "get","dataType" : "json",`

Comment: @RahulSharma yup bro error was due to return type of data which i didnt include in that method